# GCP function to function HTTP call

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call a GCP function (B) from another GCP function (A).

So far, I have:

- Created a service account and granted function invoker role
- Added to function B the service account as Function Admin
- Downloaded a json key for the created service account
- Tried to run the code locally

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

```
function_url = 'https://europe-west6-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/yyy'
json_path = "/Users/xxx44b1.json"

credentials = service_account.IDTokenCredentials.from_service_account_file( 
         json_path, 
         target_audience=function_url,
 ) 

authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
response = authed_session.post(function_url)


response.text
```

However, it does not work, and returns:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>404 Page not found</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Page not found</h1>
<h2>The requested URL was not found on this server.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Personally, I would not run anything locally to start with. Presumably all IAM roles and service accounts are set correctly. Deploy both cloud functions and invoke one of them manually under expectation that the second is to be called as well. Check the logs to see what happened. If the above approach does not work - can you update the question and provide errors from the log, please?

Comment: Are all your functions correctly deployed and tested unitary?

Comment: The function returns the exact same error I experiment locally

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your ingress settings [based on the docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#configure_ingress_settings) as follows:

```
  gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME 
  --trigger-http 
  --ingress-settings INGRESS_SETTINGS
```